# IF Statement to Delete Symbolic Link

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to remove an error from appearing on the terminal (it annoys me as it is not one that I need to be worried about).

I have the following code which will check for a broken symbolic link, and if the link is broken it will delete the link:

```
find /usr/lib/libdb.so -xtype l -delete
```

How do I change this to a iIF statement?

```
if [ broken link ] then;
    delete file
else
    do nothing
fi
```

Could anyone shed any light on this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your approach, you could try this command:

```
if [ "`find /usr/lib/libdb.so -type l -xtype l`" != "" ]; then
    echo delete file
else
    echo do nothing
fi
```

or, more concisely:

```
find /usr/lib/libdb.so -type l -xtype l -print -delete
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is the only one that seemed to work on my system!

Comment: How will this find work if it finds **more than one broken links** in `/usr/lib/libdb.so` path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this find:

```
find /usr/lib/libdb.so -type l -not -exec test -e '{}' \; -print -delete
```

`-not -test -e` will detect only broken files(links) and delete them after printing.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help, but for some reason this didn't work on my system.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but give it a try

```
FILES=`find /usr/lib/libdb.so | grep -v '\.disabled$' | sort`

for F in $FILES; do
    if [ -L $F ]; then
        if readlink -q $F >/dev/null ; then
            delete file
        else
            DO NOTHING
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, for some reason this didn't work on my systems - thanks!